# Why does puppet resource behave differently when specifying the provider

Tags: linux, puppet

I was playing around with puppet and noticed this behavior.

```
# puppet resource file /etc/passwd
file { '/etc/passwd':
  ensure   => 'file',
  content  => '{md5}7a63b133e1a086d9f35c2014b3b09218',
  ctime    => 'Thu Jan 10 17:16:11 -0700 2013',
  group    => '0',
  mode     => '644',
  mtime    => 'Thu Jan 10 17:16:11 -0700 2013',
  owner    => '0',
  selrange => 's0',
  selrole  => 'object_r',
  seltype  => 'etc_t',
  seluser  => 'system_u',
  type     => 'file',
}
```

vs

```
# puppet resource file /etc/passwd provider=posix
file { '/etc/passwd':
  ensure   => 'file',
  selrange => 's0',
  selrole  => 'object_r',
  seltype  => 'etc_t',
  seluser  => 'system_u',
}
```

This is on a Linux system where the file provider should be POSIX. Why is the output different when the provider is explicitly specified?

**Edit**: Added specific output for the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppetlabs recently stood up their own stack exchange instance and this question was answered over there: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/241/why-does-puppet-resource-behave-differently-when-specifying-the-provider/?answer=253#post-id-253